# strtotime php function not behaving as expected

Tags: php, date, strtotime, epoch

I'm trying to write a bit of php to determine the date (Y-m-d format) for the next occurrence of a given weekday.

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next monday'));
```

is returning

```
2011-08-29
```

instead of

```
2011-08-22
```

on my server. Not sure why. My server is an EC2 instance in Amazon's US East-Coast data center and it's currently 2011-08-21 9:40:00.

**EDIT 1**
Also `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next sunday'));` returns `2011-08-28` instead of today. I tried out this code on http://writecodeonline.com/php/ ... beginning to think that tester is inaccurate.

Comment: I would look more into the timezone settings of your server: "This function will use the TZ environment variable (if available) to calculate the timestamp. Since PHP 5.1.0 there are easier ways to define the timezone that is used across all date/time functions. That process is explained in the date_default_timezone_get() function page." http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: I would also advise check the timezone first. What does it say for `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today'));`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because your server is set to a certain timezone doesn't necessarily mean PHP will be acting on the same timezone. It is already Monday, August 22, 2011 in Europe, which also includes UTC. If your PHP is acting on this timezone, "next Monday" *would* be Aug. 29.

You should double-check your timezone settings in PHP. You can either run [`date_default_timezone_get()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) to check what settings your installation is using, or try forcing your PHP script to use the timezone you expect with [`date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) and seeing if you get the result you expect.

I just tested this:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New York");
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next monday')); // prints 2011-08-22
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next monday')); // prints 2011-08-29
```

Comment: I tried date_default_timezone_get() and you're correct it's set to UTC. I'm going to try changing it now.

Comment: +1, a very good point that a lot of people don't think about.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of PHP are you using? In some versions of PHP `strtotime` does have a buggy behavior.

I found that in `strtotime` manual page:

> **5.0.2**  In PHP 5 up to 5.0.2, "now" and other relative times are wrongly computed from today's midnight. This differs from other versions where it is correctly computed from current time.
>
> **5.0.0**  Microseconds began to be allowed, but they are ignored.
>
> **4.4.0**  In PHP versions prior to 4.4.0, "next" is incorrectly computed as +2. A typical solution to this is to use "+1".

Your described behavior suggests that you have a version between **5.0** and **5.0.2**.

I suggest you to check whether the difference between today and the computed "*next monday*" is higher than 7 days. If it is, subtract 7 days and you have the actual date.

Try using that code:

```
$days = ((strtotime('next monday') - time()) / 60 / 60 / 24);
if ($days >= 8) {
  $days -= 7;
}
```

I know there is [date_diff](http://php.net/date_diff) function, but if your PHP version is so low as I think, it isn't available for you (sorry, only 5.3.0 and higher).

Comment: Does anyone even offer hosting for 5.0.2 anymore?

Comment: Maybe own server, not upgraded for a long time?

Comment: True enough. FWIW, I wasn't trying to imply you were wrong. I was just surprised by the idea of someone still using 5.0. I'm annoyed that my host hasn't rolled out 5.3 yet. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the expected behaviour, since Monday hasn't passed strtotime sees it as the Next Monday.

Answer (score 0):

"Next", when used with weekdays, generally means the first one after the next closest one. For example if today is Sunday the 21st then the "next" Monday is not tomorrow the 22nd but the following Monday the 29th.

I know this is not necessarily intuitive and not recognized universally but I believe that that is how `strtotime()` interprets "next".

EDIT: I have confirmed via my own tests that I am incorrect and that "next" should return the first upcoming weekday (the 22nd in my example above). I will leave this answer here unedited as it and the comment below may be helpful to others.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. To avoid confusion, PHP separated 'next Monday' (meaning the upcoming Monday from now) opposed to 'Monday next week' (being the Monday following the upcoming one). So, if today is August 21, 'next Monday' would return August 22, 'last Saturday' would return August 20, and 'Monday next week' would return August 29.